# Check if an event listener is already listenning to an object (to avoid duplicate actions)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page looks like:

```
<a class="myClass">1</a>
<a class="myClass">2</a>
<a class="myClass">3</a>

<a class"add_anchor">Add Anchor</a>
```

When the page is fully loaded, I bind a listener to `a.myClass` that executes a certain function `f`.

The click on `Add Anchor` adds via AJAX a new `a.myClass` to the list. So, to listen to all `a.myClass`s (the newly added and the initial ones), I should call the listener twice, the overall code looks like:

```
function listenToMyClassClick{
$('.myClass').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  
        f();
});
}

listenToMyClassClick();

$('.addAnchor').click(function(e){
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                         listenToMyClassClick();                               
                    }
                    });  
});
```

As a result, `f` is executed two times. How can I check with jQuery that a listener is already executing so that I don't execute it another time?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ (instead of adding listeners every time you add a link to DOM)

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, thank you for the quick guidance. I am reading your link.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, waw your page adresses directly my issue. the keyword `delegation` is magical. thanks again. I think I will rewrite the whole project (I was adding listeners whenver needed :-D)

Comment: Does event propagation requires my anchors to be listed in unordered list?? I have anchors inside divs and it is not working. I don't see explicitly that the structure given by the documentation is the required one

Comment: No...you are doing,something wrong. Make sure the parent you are binding the event listener to exists at bind time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delegated event, like Sergiu suggests. Instead of binding a click event to an element that exists in a dynamic list of elements, bind a click event to the element's parent, which will still raise a click event even when you click one its children. This is called event bubbling. Here's a snippet of code showing how to do it using jQuery:

```
// Attach a delegated event handler
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
    f();
});
```

You bind the click event directly to "#List", being the parent and tell it to specifically listen for events from "a" elements, which is defined in the second parameter.